# React set checked property on componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, forms, dom, radio-button

I have multipage form and I want to set checked fields if I go back, I figured out how to do it but it doesn't work as I expected.

I find the elements I need to check, assign the attribute but nothing happens on UI, checked property is there in Chrome devtools

Here is the code:

```
 if (Object.keys(this.props.data).length > 0) {
      const elements = this.formRef.current.elements;
      const IDs = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
      IDs.map(id => {
        if (elements[id]) {
          if (Array.from(elements[id]).length > 1) {
            let radio = Array.from(elements[id]).find(el => el.value == this.props.data.subData[id])
             let r = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(radio);
             r.checked = true;
          } else {
            if (id === 1) {
              this.setState({
                dropdownValue: this.props.data.subData[id]
              })
            }
            let r = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(elements[id]);
             r.value = this.props.data.subData[id]
          }
        }
      })
    }
  }
```

Here is a component:

```
 <Radio
     label='...'
     desc='...'
     id='...'
     name='...'
     options={[
          { id: '...', label: '...', value: '...', name: '...' },
          { id: '...', label: '...', value: '...', name: '...' }]}
 />
```

That returns this:

```
<div className='form-input-group'>
        <label>{label} <span>{desc}</span></label>
        {options.map((option, index) => (
          <RadioItem
            key={index}
            option={option}
            defaultValue={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
```

Comment: Why not set the values in the `state` rather than looking for the dom nodes? could you post a part of your render function, at least the part where you paint these checkboxes?

Comment: I haven't worked on this from beginning, it has weird structure. I would probably do it like you say. In render there are components like Radio, Input component, it's not classic input with handleChange and stuff. That's why it needs to be done this way..

Comment: So, which library are the `Radio` and `Input` components from? Do they receive a `checked` value or something similar? Could you post a part of this render?

Comment: I'll edit the post, these components are custom component

Comment: And is it possible to edit this custom components so that they work correctly? meaning that, they could receive the value in the props and handle it in the state. This, so that you don't need to do any hacks for handling these type of situations and do it like it is supposed to in React